# Are these "temporary defense gained by discarding cards" markers?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

I just got the *Race for the Galaxy: The Brink of War* expansion, which I haven't played yet. It comes with some additional Takeover markers. These two markers look like "temporary defense gained by discarding cards" markers:

[image: Mystery marker from Race for the Galaxy: The Brink of War expansion]

I can't find the card that gives this power. The rulebook states they are for *Rebel Pact*:

> Two counters are supplied to track a player’s total possible Military on
>   defense (for use with *Rebel Pact*).

But *Rebel Pact* is part of the *Rebel vs. Imperium* expansion. In Settle phase, it gives

> +2 defense against a [takeover] for each... (Rebel military world) in your tableau; +1 defense for each other [military world]

[image: Rebel Pact]

and the *Rebel vs. Imperium* expansion already comes with markers for tracking *Rebel Pacts* defense:

> The *Rebel Pact* provides 2 Military for each Rebel military world
>    and 1 Military for each non-Rebel military world in a player’s
>    tableau at the start of Settle, when defending against takeovers. [image: Rebel Pact Military marker]

**What card are these markers used with? What do they mean?**

[image: Mystery marker from Race for the Galaxy: The Brink of War expansion]

Answer (score 2):

According to the Rulebook, next to a picture of these markers:

> Two counters are supplied to track a player’s total possible Military on
>   defense (for use with Rebel Pact).

These markers are for use on your military track to show you (and your opponents) your potential maximum defense if you count both your defensive bonus from Rebel Pact and all your sources of temporary Military (denoted by the discard symbol on the token).

Page 8 of the rulebook has an illustration.

Comment: I don't think this is it. I've edited my question to include reasons I think the rulebook is wrong.

Comment: I think that the tokens that only show the Rebel Pact token are to be placed to show what your defense would be if you didn't use any of your extra discard-for-military powers, while the tokens in question show your maximum defense if you used all of your discard-for-military powers.